# Jquery div toggle only working for one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have a div show one of two images, depending on which div a user hovers over. The solution below works, but only for a mouseover of `#FH_Blurb`, a mouseover of `#HDS_Blurb` doesn't do anything.

Any idea why? Both images exist in the images folder.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-4" id="features_3_content_left">
            <div class="feature" id="FH_Blurb">
                <h4>Fizz+Hummer</h4>
                <p>Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-4">
            <div class="features_3_content_center">
                <img src="images/FH_MainMenu.png" class="img-responsive" id="features3_FH_image" alt="img">
                <img src="images/HDS_MainMenu.png" class="img-responsive" id="features3_HDS_image" alt="img">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-4" id="features_3_content_right">
            <div class="feature" id="HDS_Blurb">
                <div>
                <h4 class="we_make_games_HDS_text">Human Delivery Service</h4>
                <p>Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum.
                </p>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
PicChanger: function(){

    $('#features3_FH_image, #features3_HDS_image').hide();           

    $('#FH_Blurb').hover(function() {
      $('#features3_FH_image').toggle();
    });

    $('#HDS_Blurb').hover(function() {
      $('#features3_HDS_image').toggle();
    });
},
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?  For me the code works fine.  I didn't include any CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/4707r744/

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint in the hover callback?

Comment: @Barmar Ah I see, what's causing it to push the blurb down?

Comment: The blurb is below the images.

Comment: Seems fine to me. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/urhehfnr BTW, your column classes are redundant. Just use the smallest.

Comment: If you comment out the first code segment ( `$('#FH_Blurb').hover(function() {$('#features3_FH_image').toggle();}); ` ) does the second toggle work?

Comment: If your using visual studios, could you try inserting a break point and going line by line?

Comment: @IanWise Commenting out the first segment makes it so that neither of the toggles work. I'm not using VS, this is written in Brackets.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure what you mean by "below" in this instance. Are you referring to z-index? They're on the same index as far as I can tell.

Comment: @isherwood Sorry, tagged the wrong person.

Comment: I mean they're ordered vertically on the page. When the images are hidden,  the two blurbs are adjacent. When the image appears, the second blurb has to move to make space for the image.

Comment: I solved the problem...I realized I had the css of HDS_Image defaulted to `hidden`. You can all feel free to banish me from SO for that careless mistake haha.

Comment: I thought you was aware, the question comes off totally different.

Answer (score -1):

try with this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      //code here   });
```

//Edit

try setting each image on different div.

Comment: If that were the problem it wouldn't work with either element.

Comment: try setting each image on different div.

Answer (score -1):

You need a `br` tag.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-4" id="features_3_content_left">
            <div class="feature" id="FH_Blurb">
                <h4>Fizz+Hummer</h4>
                <p>Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div><br>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-4">
            <div class="features_3_content_center">
                <img src="images/FH_MainMenu.png" class="img-responsive" id="features3_FH_image" alt="img">
                <img src="images/HDS_MainMenu.png" class="img-responsive" id="features3_HDS_image" alt="img">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-4" id="features_3_content_right">
            <div class="feature" id="HDS_Blurb">
                <div>
                <h4 class="we_make_games_HDS_text">Human Delivery Service</h4>
                <p>Epsum factorial non deposit quid pro quo hic escorol. Olypian quarrels et gorilla congolium sic ad nauseum.
                </p>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. This totally defeats the purpose of a grid system.

Answer (score -1):

What I recommend using the handleOut callback with hover:

```
$(selector).hover(function(){
 //do something 
}, function(){
 //do something 
});
```

Then use either, .css/ .animate/ .slideUp, .slideDown or whatever you feel is appropriate for your final result.

Also check out the .stop() and .delay() jQuery APIs to prevent propagation.

Comment: The only form of `toggle` that's deprecated is using it with two function arguments to run each of them alternatively. That was removed in jQuery 1.9. Using it to toggle visibility of an element is not deprecated.